# How can I group entries based on a string value?

Tags: templating, entries

I have been able to successfully [group entries via dateTime field](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16748/how-can-i-group-entries-based-on-a-datetime-field). I have been trying to carry over the same type of logic only instead of using `.date` just key off of the field value.

```
{# Get all entries from the section. #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('mySection') %}

{# Loop through the entries and get the user account associated with each. #}
{% for profiles in entries %}
    {% set users = profiles.userAccount %}

    {% if users|length %}
        {% for year, user in users|group('myYearField') %}
            <h4>{{ year }}</h4> {# 2016 #}
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                {% for user in users %}
                    <li><a href="{{ profiles.url }}">{{ user.name }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Currently what I am getting is:

```
2016
    User
2016
    User
...
```

What I am trying to get (I swear I had this working at one point) is this:

```
2016
    User
    User

2017
   User
   User
```

**EDIT**

It seems my trouble comes from not accessing the `users` field correctly.
Updated (but still incorrect) example:

```
{% set allProfiles = craft.entries.section('mySection') %}
{% if allProfiles|length %}
    {{ allProfiles|length }} {# 3 #}
    {% for profiles in allProfiles %}
        {% for profile in profiles.userAccount %}
            {% for year, user in profile|group('yearFieldHandle') %}
                <h1>{{ year }}</h1>  {# No output #}
                <h2>{{ profile.firstName }}</h2>    {# Bob #}
                <h3>{{ profile.myYear }}</h3> {# 2016 #}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: To be clear, is `myYearField` a DateTime or PlainText field?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. It is a plain text field in the CP.
Users are presented a drop-down list of years on their profile page that populates `myYearField` within the CP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There’s a lot to unpack here. Before I get to the solution, I’ll step through each of your examples, line-by-line. Hopefully that will help explain the behavior you’re seeing.

### First Example

```
{# Get all entries from the section. #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('mySection') %}
```

Your comment is correct – this will fetch all the entries from section `mySection` and assign them to a new variable called `entries`.

```
{# Loop through the entries and get the user account associated with each. #}
{% for profiles in entries %}
```

Start a loop on the `entries` variable. Within the loop, each profile entry will be represented by a `profiles` variable.

*Note: it’s misleading to call your variable “profiles” rather than “profile”, since it will only represent a single profile entry.*

```
    {% set users = profiles.userAccount %}
```

Fetch all of the user accounts related to the current profile (`profiles`) via the `userAccount` field, and assign them to a new variable called `users`.

```
    {% if users|length %}
```

Only do the following if there were any related users…

```
        {% for year, user in users|group('myYearField') %}
```

Turn the users (`users`) that are related to the current profile (`profiles`) into a multi-dimensional array, grouped by their `myYearField` field values. Then start a loop on that multi-dimensional array. Within the loop, each `myYearField` value will be represented by a `year` variable, and the array of grouped user accounts will be represented by a `user` variable.

*Note: This is where things start really going wrong. You want to group **all** of your users by year – not just the ones that are related to the current profile. Also, your choice of “user” as a variable name here is misleading since it’s actually an array of grouped users; not a single user.*

```
            <h4>{{ year }}</h4> {# 2016 #}
```

Output the current grouping’s `myYearField` value, which was assigned to a `year` variable.

```
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                {% for user in users %}
```

Start a loop on the same `users` variable that you’re already in the middle of looping through. `users` here refers to the same `users` variable that was defined in the 3rd codeblock.

```
                    <li><a href="{{ profiles.url }}">{{ user.name }}</a></li>
```

Output the profile entry’s (`profiles`) URL, and the current user’s (`user`) name.

```
                {% endfor %}
```

Close out the loop on the user accounts related to the current profile entry (`users`).

```
            </ul>
        {% endfor %}
```

Close out the loop on the multi-dimensional array of year-user groupings based on the user accounts related to the current profile entry (`users`).

```
    {% endif %}
```

Close out the conditional checking if there any users related to the current profile entry.

```
{% endfor %}
```

Close out the loop on the profile entries (`entries`).

---

### Second Example

```
{% set allProfiles = craft.entries.section('mySection') %}
```

Fetch all the entries from section `mySection` and assign them to a new variable called `allProfiles`.

```
{% if allProfiles|length %}
```

Only do the following if there were any profile entries…

```
    {{ allProfiles|length }} {# 3 #}
```

Output the total number of profile entries.

```
    {% for profiles in allProfiles %}
```

Start a loop on the `allProfiles` variable. Within the loop, each profile entry will be represented by a `profiles` variable.

*Note: as with the last example, it’s misleading to call your variable “profiles” rather than “profile”, since it will only represent a single profile entry.*

```
        {% for profile in profiles.userAccount %}
```

Fetch all of the user accounts related to the current profile (`profiles`) via the `userAccount` field. Start a loop on the user accounts. Within the loop, each user account will be represented by a `profile` variable.

*Note: it’s misleading to call your variable “profile”, since it is actually the user account, not the profile entry.*

```
            {% for year, user in profile|group('yearFieldHandle') %}
```

Turn the current user account (`profile`) into a multi-dimensional array, grouped by its properties’ `yearFieldHandle` sub-property values (which isn’t a thing). Then start a loop on that multi-dimensional array. Within the loop, each `yearFieldHandle` value will be represented by a `year` variable, and the array of grouped user account properties will be represented by a `user` variable.

*Note: Since `profile` is a single element (the user account) and not an array of elements, nothing about this is likely doing what you expected it to.*

```
                <h1>{{ year }}</h1>  {# No output #}
```

Output the current grouping’s `yearFieldHandle` value, which was assigned to a `year` variable. (This is the equivalent of doing something like `profile.id.yearFieldHandle`. It’s expected that you wouldn’t get any output.)

```
                <h2>{{ profile.firstName }}</h2>    {# Bob #}
```

Output the user account’s first name.

```
                <h3>{{ profile.myYear }}</h3> {# 2016 #}
```

Output the user account’s `myYear` custom field value.

```
            {% endfor %}
```

Close out the loop on the multi-dimensional array of year-user account property groupings based on the current user account defined by the parent loop.

```
        {% endfor %}
```

Close out the loop on the user accounts related to the current profile entry.

```
    {% endfor %}
```

Close out the loop on the profile entries (`allProfiles`).

```
{% endif %}
```

Close out the conditional checking if there any profile entries.

---

### Solution

To group all of your profiles by their related user accounts’ custom date fields, first let’s load the profiles, [eager-loaded](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/eager-loading-elements) with their related user accounts:

```
{% set profiles = craft.entries({
    section: 'userProfiles',
    with: ['userAccount']
}) %}
```

Next let’s group the profiles by the `myYear` custom field on their related user accounts:

```
{% set profilesByYear = profiles|group('userAccount[0].myYear') %}
```

Now we can loop through the years, and their corresponding user profiles/accounts:

```
{% for year, yearProfiles in profilesByYear %}
    <h1>{{ year }}</h1>

    {% for profile in yearProfiles %}
        {% set user = profile.userAccount[0] ?? null %}
        {% if user %}
            <h2>{{ user.firstName }}</h2>
            <h3>{{ user.myYear }}</h3>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is a fantastic response. Thank you for taking the time to write this all out!